# Android Volley Post Request Обновить

Tags: java, android

```
    void runParsrepage(final CharSequence s){

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);  // this = context
    url = "http://www.m-translate.com.ua/";
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response
                    Log.d("Response", response);
                    String fulpage = response;

                    Log.i(fulpage,fulpage);

                    String repllaced = fulpage.replaceAll("\n", "");

                    if (repllaced.contains("html")) {
                        MyTask mt = new MyTask();
                        mt.execute(repllaced);
                    }


                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error

                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("translate_to", "en");
            params.put("translate_from", "ru");
            params.put("text", "Четверг");

            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
}
```

Как обновить запрос ?
Если я сделаю запрос `params.put("text", "Четверг");`
А потом поменяю на  params.put("text", "Вторник");
И заново скомпилирую, то все равно отправиться запрос Четверг

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил 
   queue.getCache().clear();